# Axis2 issue: xsi:type= returns on soap message when multiple web services exist in the same eclipse project

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, apache-axis

xsi:type comes back in the soap envelope when multiple web services exist in the same Eclipse project.  The WSDL's don't appear to change, just how the soap message returns.  Why?  How can this be prevented?

Here is the java web service:

```
package com.fedins.certificateservice.service.certificatelist;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(targetNamespace = "com.fedins.certificateservice.service.certificatelist")
//@Addressing(enabled = false)
public class CertificateListService {

    public CertificateListService() {
        super();
    }

    @WebMethod
    //  @WebResult(name = "CertificateList")
    public Sparky[] getCertificateList() {

        //List<Sparky> myReturn = new ArrayList<Sparky>();
        Sparky[] myReturn = new Sparky[2];

        Sparky myCert0 = new Sparky();
        myCert0.setGoober("2342342");
        myReturn[0] = myCert0;
        //myReturn.add(myCert0);

        Sparky myCert10 = new Sparky();
        myCert10.setGoober("2342343434342");
        myReturn[1] = myCert10;
        //myReturn.add(myCert10);

        System.out.println("ME WANT CAKE");
        return myReturn;
    }

}
```

Here is the second web service:

```
package com.fedins.certificateservice.service.franklist;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService()
public class FrankListService {

    public FrankListService() {
        super();
    }

    @WebMethod
    public String getFrankList() {

        return "pokemon";
    }
}
```

This is an example when multiple services are in the Eclipse project:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <dlwmin:getCertificateListResponse xmlns:dlwmin="com.fedins.certificateservice.service.certificatelist" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <return xsi:type="sparky">
            <goober>2342342</goober>
         </return>
         <return xsi:type="sparky">
            <goober>2342343434342</goober>
         </return>
      </dlwmin:getCertificateListResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is an example of when only this service is in the Eclipse project:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <dlwmin:getCertificateListResponse xmlns:dlwmin="com.fedins.certificateservice.service.certificatelist" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <return>
            <goober>2342342</goober>
         </return>
         <return>
            <goober>2342343434342</goober>
         </return>
      </dlwmin:getCertificateListResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: This seems to only be an issue when the service is returning an array or list.  Also, if both web services are in the same namespace, then it isn't an issue.

Comment: This appears to be an issue with Axis2.  It is using the object name in the xsi type but it should not have the xsi type or it should have it namespaced.  In the example above, it would be correct if it came back as xsi:type="dlwmin:sparky" but it only has xsi:type="sparky"